# UI code goes missing when deploying to Heroku

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, heroku

I have a Spring-MVC app that uses AngularJS for the front-end and Java in the backend. The java code is in src/main/java and the UI code is in src/main/resources/static. I'm building a fat jar using Maven.

Running locally = everything works. 
I can also run the jar from the command line and everything works. 
When I deploy to Heroku, the app returns a 404 on / ... it seems like it can't find the UI code anywhere.

I have an identical app with a different (less fancy) AngularJS UI, and it deploys to Heroku without any issues. The only real difference is the UI code exists at the parent src/main/resources/static while my custom app uses gulp - and gulp builds the ui code src/main/resources/static/dist. My Maven POM moves that /dist to target/classes/static when I run the package job, and that's working fine... After mvn clean package I can run my app through IntelliJ or at the command line using java -jar target/blah.jar. But when I push it to Heroku I get an application error, and the Heroku log cites a 404 on path="/".

Note my starting point for these projects was the Stormpath examples for spring-boot-web-angular. The stock example deploys fine with same Procfile, so the only difference is the /dist that my custom UI code has - but Maven should be taking care of that.

My Procfile contains:

> web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/*.jar

Pom excerpt that copies the UI code to the right spot in target/:

> ```
>        <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.0.1</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <id>copy-resources</id>
>                     <phase>validate</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>copy-resources</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
>                         <resources>
>                             <resource>
>                                 <directory>src/main/resources/static/dist</directory>
>                                 <filtering>false</filtering>
>                             </resource>
>                         </resources>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
> ```

I've been googling for days and reached out to Heroku support, but they said they can't help.

I can't tell if the Maven piece isn't getting picked up when I git push heroku master (after packing locally), or if I'm missing a config option or something in my Procfile.

Would very much appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: btw, I also tried changing the phase of copy-resources to "package" just in case the heroku build was skipping the "validate" phase for some reason... same result.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce locally by running `mvn clean install` and then `heroku local web`?

Comment: @codefinger yes, heroku local web gives the same result.

Comment: So I got the deployment to work using the heroku-maven-plugin ... so it's working now... I still don't understand why the git push heroku master drops the UI code, but at least I'm able to do what I needed to get done using the Maven plugin

Comment: I don't think it matters that it's in `target/classes/static`. It needs to be in `WEB-INF/classes/static` in the `*.jar` file. Is it there?

Comment: I don't have a WEB-INF anywhere in my code. Spring was taking care of that for me (I think)... I'm quite new at this, and started with an sdk example template that had no WEB-INF.

Comment: If you're using Spring, you might consider Pivotal Web Services instead--it runs the actual code you push (generally a fat jar if you're using Boot) instead of rebuilding it and potentially screwing it up.